Can RP2040 GPIOs be used as a "togglable ground" for NMOS Array?
I'm working on a project that requires me to control an LED inside a button (it's labeled 5V and I'm assuming it has a built-in current limiting resistor based on some reviews). Since the RP2040 is a 3.3V device, I can't drive the LED directly with the GPIO.
I could find a separate NMOS transistor drive the LED in the usual way (GPIO to gate, Source to gnd, ect), but I have a free channel on an array of BSS138 transistors that I'm using as a logic level converter for something else. I'd like to repurpose this channel if possible.
The issue is the logic level shifter connects the gates of all BSS138s to the low side 3.3v source, so I can't connect a GPIO to the gate to control the NMOS. Instead, I figured I could connect the GPIO to the source and use the low logic level to pull it down to ground when I want the LED to turn on, and high logic level to prevent current flow turning the LED off.
Is is safe to use the GPIO pin like this? From what I can tell on the datasheet, the GPIOs can sink a max of 50mA combined and this would pull about 10 mA and I don't think any other GPIOs are going to be sinking.
I'm also fine with my backup plan, which is to cut the traces to one of the channels and manually connect it the traditional way.
Image for Reference:


This is a perfectly usable circuit in general. A couple of things to check when using it.

The threshold voltage of the FET must be low enough that it is turned on sufficiently at 3.3V for your required LED current. The BSS138 should be fine for your setup, tick.
The whole LED current will flow through the GPIO of the RP2040, so make sure the IO pins are capable of handling that. 10mA seems reasonable, for a GPIO pin. If the datasheet says this is acceptable, then, tick.

This is actually a common structure used as a bidirectional level shifter for things like I2C.
